# Angular js Datatables footer add links

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-datatables

I want to add links in the footer part of the Datatable where pagination details comes  i.e. I want to add the links in between of 'showing 1 of 20 entries in 40' and the pagination's pre next buttons.How can this be done? Any Suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add it to left side or right side of your footer table, i added to left side where it shows `Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_`

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
    "language": {
    "info": "Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_ <a href='http://www.example.com'>Link1</a>"
    }
  });
});
```

Using **angular**-datatable, again the way you specify the options will change based on the table you defined and angular version [Angular1 option](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#/withOptions) and [Angular2 option](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/with-options)

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withLanguage(
"sInfo":"Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_ <a href='http://www.example.com'>Link1</a>",
);
```

Comment: change `<a href='http://www.example.com'>Link1</a>` to `<button type="button" ng-click='http://www.example.com'>Link1</button>`

Comment: on clicking nothing happens....  f12 inspected as...<button class="text-primary" ng-click="selectAll();">Select All Visible</button>

Comment: do you have `selectAll` function in your current controller. `$scope.selectAll = function () {alert("selected")};` add this and alert will be fired when you click on link

Comment: if you want to show links to only some datatable's then follow this: create a directive like `app.directive(showLinks, function () {})` and in your html add `show-links="true"` to dataTable element, then in your directive check `attr.showLinks === true` then only add those links to `sInfo` otherwise not.

Comment: thank u.. I hv the method in the controller .. calling it from a link outside the datatable workes but not with the link kept in datatable (nothing happens on click)... I have also tried to resolve the issue using $compile but still no luck.. why is this happening? any solution?

Comment: i found that we can not add buttons as just links, here is the official way to do it http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#/withButtons

Comment: I think the issue is something else... because when I keep the selectAll function in directive scope itself , it gets called , but keeping that in the controller do not work (no call)